# Simplifying a derivative with respect to a linear combination of variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose I have a smooth function $f(x,y)$.

And I am to find the $n^{th}$ order derivative wrt $\alpha x + \beta y$, explicitly:

$$\frac{d^n}{d(\alpha x + \beta y)^n} f(x,y) $$

$(1)$ Generally, speaking is this a well posed question, to ask to find such a derivative?

I have a concrete example, let $f(x,y)=\exp(\alpha x + \beta y)^k$ for some integer $k$.

Then it is well posed in this case since I can simply perform a substitution.

My second question pertains to the case where this is well posed.

$(2)$ Can we simplify a derivative of the form $\frac{d^n}{d(\alpha x + \beta y)^n}$ to be some a summation over products of $ \frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}$?

Any pointers and help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the most general sense with no additional context, such a derivative does not make sense without knowing what other variable is being held constant. In the language of linear algebra, to take a partial derivative the way you are describing requires a change of basis to a new coordinate system. Then the partial derivative is defined by taking the derivative wrt your variable $u=ax+by$ while holding another variable $v=h(x,y)$ constant.

Comment: I think your $$\frac{d^n}{d(\alpha x + \beta y)^n} f(x,y) $$
should be $$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial(\alpha x + \beta y)^n} f(x,y). $$